# how to join on varchar(32) and binary(16) columns in sybase?

Tags: sql, sybase

I want to join two tables on a UUID. table A's UUID is represented as varchar(32). table B's UUID is represented as binary(16).

what's the best way to join a varchar to a binary column?

I've tried using some sybase functions for this, but I'm getting different results and unsure of why:

```
select hextobigint('0x000036ca4c4c11d88b8dcd1344cdb512')
3948051912944290701
select convert(bigint,0x000036ca4c4c11d88b8dcd1344cdb512)
-2877434794219274240
```

what am I missing about convert and hextobigint? I must be misundstanding at least one of these functions. thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know anything about sybase or these functions specifically, but... for performance reasons, and the health of your relationship with the DBAs, pick a datatype, and stick to it.  Seriously, don't have two (or more) different types of `Id`s (UUID or whatever) that you expect to join on - having to do a conversion for every comparison is annoying and performance-degrading.

Comment: I agree 100%, this is not a database I designed or have any control over. I'm just trying to query it (it's actually a join across 2 schemas)

Comment: In that case... are you able to get the hex as the `char` representation, or convert the text string to the binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it eventually with the help of some colleagues:

```
select strtobin(convert(char(32), '000036ca4c4c11d88b8dcd1344cdb512'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the `select convert(bigint,0x000036ca4c4c11d88b8dcd1344cdb512)`.

If you remove the first zeros it'll give you the same result:

```
select hextobigint('0x000036ca4c4c11d88b8dcd1344cdb512')
```

and

```
select convert(bigint,0x36ca4c4c11d88b8dcd1344cdb512)
```

Comment: weird thing is, it doesn't give me the same answer then either. I've updated the question to not use a unsigned bigint, but still gives me a different result.

Comment: after some testing I found it.

Comment: thanks, but I'm still unsure why the two functions yield a different result with 0 padding. doesn't seem like they should.

Comment: @PaulSanwald well this is the best that I can do for you